# Serverless with Google Cloud Functions - delete old deployment ZIPs

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-functions, serverless-framework

Each time my Serverless function is deployed with `serverless deploy`, Serverless appears to package up the function with its dependencies and place it in a new folder in Google Cloud Storage and re-deploy the function.

The problem is, over time my old deployment ZIPs are still sitting in Google Cloud Storage, collecting dust and using up space. Is there a way to get Serverless to delete any previous deployment ZIPs after a successful deploy?

Comment: This is the behavior even if you use the gcloud tool instead of the serverless tool. At least for gcloud, there's currently no provided way to delete older zip files automatically after the new function gets deployed.

Comment: A real shame...hopefully they add this functionality soon.